# RSpec/Capybara javascript testing throwing driver error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the following TestHelpers library included in the best_in_place gem. The function I am trying to use, `bip_text`, looks like this:

```
module TestHelpers
    include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper

    def bip_text(model, attr, new_value)
      id = BestInPlace::Utils.build_best_in_place_id model, attr
      find("##{id}").click
      execute_script <<-JS
        $("##{id} input[name='#{attr}']").val('#{escape_javascript new_value.to_s}');
        $("##{id} form").submit();
      JS
      wait_for_ajax
end
```

When trying to run it in my specs it throws the following error (with stack trace included):

```
Failure/Error: find("##{id}").trigger('click')

     Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
       Capybara::Driver::Node#trigger
     # /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/driver/node.rb:99:in `trigger'
     # /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:341:in `block in trigger'
     # /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:341:in `trigger'
     # ./app/helpers/test_helper.rb:6:in `bip_area'
     # ./spec/features/admin/admin_can_edit_a_task_inline_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What's particularly strange about this case is that I have another spec that runs it just fine. Just for good measure, this is how I am calling it: `bip_text @task, :title, "New Task"` (The TestHelpers are required in my rails_helper)

I scoured the internet for answers, and found that some suggested using Capybara-webkit instead of capybara. What exactly is the difference? I don't want the overhead of needing the binary webkit requires if I can solve this with pure capybara.

Comment: may be related to [Fix bip_select by removing unsupported "Node#trigger" call](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/pull/588/commits/ca759aab6e5ca270c982cbeaeaf165dbfa056d97)

Comment: @Rcordoval not working for me. Here's the related issue with more details on GH: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/600

Comment: What are you using as your JavaScript driver? It seems like maybe different drivers are being used in the specs.